# How to get current user's document id in Swift using Firebase Firestore?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    
    guard currentUser != nil else {return}
    let docRef = db.collection("UserProfiles").document("sWD6Sr11yimSFrpZ9B0m")
    
    docRef.getDocument { document, error in

        guard error == nil else {return}

        guard let name = document?.get("name") as? String else {return}
        guard let lastname = document?.get("lastname") as? String else {return}
        self.nameLabel.text = name+" "+lastname

    }
```

Manual display of current user's documentID = "sWD6Sr11yimSFrpZ9B0m"

How can I get the document ID of the current user automatically?

[Saved document IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qr8EF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
```

will return current user id who is logged in

you can get all document ids of a collection but not current! firebase doesn't know what is current user document or id. You just get current user uid and save document with uid and get it with uid

```
 db.collection("Seeker").getDocuments { querySnapshot, error in
                guard let snapshot = querySnapshot, error == nil else {return}
                let documentIDs = snapshot.documents.map({$0.documentID})
                print(documentIDs)
            }
```

this is how you get all documents ids ...

if you want to keep track document id

```
self.db.collection("Seeker").document(userId).setData([
                        "email": email,
                        "role" : userType.title
                    ])
```

so you can get Seeker with his user id as document id

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response. Current user's uid and documentID are different. Current user's uid = "3C4PCsrbYFdBkUncAJTkzITV2nn1"  Current user's documentID = "sWD6Sr11yimSFrpZ9B0m"

Comment: you can get all document ids of a collection but not current! firebase doesn't know what is current user document or id. You just get current user uid and save document with uid and get it with uid

Comment: Thank you for your information. I will get the solution.